# How can one prevent the gadgeteer edge in Savage Worlds from becoming overpowered without banning or nerfing it into oblivion?

Tags: savage-worlds, balance

According to the text in the Deluxe Edition of Savage Worlds, the Gadgeteer edge available to weird scientists (WS) allows a player to indefinitely accumulate devices at a rate of one per session, effectively giving a WS every power in the game, if played conservatively. Does anyone have links to any published sources or effective house rules that allow the edge to still be useful and fun without being game-breaking?

Answer (score 18):

There are a few mitigating aspects which have limited the Edge's use for the player who has it in my game, which is Deadlands Reloaded.

Firstly, Gadgeteer with RAW is limited to powers of the character's rank or lower that are available to Mad Scientists.  This actually reduces the number of powers available significantly.

Also remember that the device created by Gadgeteer burns out once its Power Points are used and cannot be recharged.

I also tend to assume that the temporary nature of the device means that even unused it will eventually fall apart, so depending on what the players are doing you could rule that a device only lasts a session.  This might be a little harsh though, but its worth considering.

You could also go down the route of the device being more susceptable to failiure compared to normal - perhaps on a 1 or 2 on the skill die?  I don't use this though and my gut feeling is it is probably a little harsh.

If all else fails, and you feel the player is still abusing the system, you could talk to them about your concerns and they may rein in a little.

Comment: This hits all the highlights of how to run the Edge both in accordance with the Rules As Written, and the spirit of things~ These are temporary solutions with short lifespans, for use in the field.

Comment: I played a character with that edge (or a similar one) and we played it this way.  The utility is being able create something on the spot, not accumulate tons of powers/gadgets.

Comment: Completely agree; I think the feel is similiar to the Scavenger Edge--essentially a one-shot "miracle" in your backpack.

Comment: Aye.  The fact that the description states the the item is "jury-rigged" shows the intention of the power.  Having a stash isn't a game killer either.  They will likely blow up on a roll of a 1 and they don't recharge power points.

Answer (score 6):

Working in concert with Phil's insight on the **Gadgeteer** Edge, present the player with opportunities too good not to use up those devices. I don't know of any player that will both *risk* their character's life and pass up an opportunity to be *amazing*.

It's good general advice to have a good idea of player character capabilities (keep copies of their character sheets) when crafting scenes and adventures. You want to both challenge them and provide opportunities for them to bask in the spotlight.

Comment: An excellent answer.  I find it particularly fun and challenging to think up twists on encounters that suites the use of a particular power only available through Gadgeteer.  If time pressure is also added into the mix then it gives the players some difficult decisions to make.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the rules assume that player will use them up quickly. This rule is flawed as they could accumulate them as you say. The requirements to be a Gadgeteer are quite high and it seams to be that you would need to focus on it at character creation. So not to use the Jury Rigged devices as you create them would quickly limit the party's total effectiveness. Hence saving them up for that really big encounter probably means that they have made earlier ones much harder. I would say it is swings and roundabouts. Your choices are simple really, leave it as it says after all the players are really just trading there short term effectiveness for a long term improvement. Hence lots of small encounters and no big bad ones will after a while change there behaviour. Or say that they loss one power point each session as after all they are Jury Rigged Devices and they don't retain charge well.

Answer (score 1):

The new rules of 2018 edition makes it very limited now because weird scientist have to limite their devices by sharing the same power point pool between all of his devices.

And now he has to define how many points from the pool will be available to all of his devices, otherwise he will have to transfer points from one device to other with tinkering.

He may let some power points free to use in his improvised devices, at least 3 which is now the maximum power points to put into an improvised device, which means he can no longer use spells of 4 pps or higher to insert into the device, which will still be destroyed after the first use.